# awk if-then-else statement error

Tags: if-statement, awk

I am writing an if-then-else statement using awk in a bash script.

What I would like to do is identify lines with col 1 values not matching a particular string (rs or chr) and append a prefix (chr) to the col 1 values for those identified lines. All lines with the matched string should print as they were - no appending.

My line of code so far is:

```
awk '{if (! ($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/)) {($1 == "chr"$1); print $0}}; else {print $0}' filename > newfilename
```

I keep on receiving syntax error messages with this code.

I can perform the identification and the appending successfully on their own but am having problems combining them into one command.

Comment: `($1 == "chr"$1)` is a condition, not an assignment. use single equal sign for assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With idiomatic awk you can rewrite this as

```
awk '$1!~/rs/ && $1!~/chr/ {$1="chr"$1}1'
```

or if you like

```
awk '!($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/) {$1="chr"$1}1'
```

or, equivalently

```
awk '!(/^rs/ || /^chr/) {$1="chr"$1}1'
```

you can avoid assignment since there is no further action other than printing with

```
awk '!(/^rs/ || /^chr/) {print "chr"$0;next}1'
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I used the second option which has worked a treat!

Comment: careful - `$1!~/rs/ && $1!~/chr/` is not equivalent to `!($1 ~ /rs/ || /chr/)` , nor is `!($1 ~ /rs/ || /chr/)` equivalent to `!(/^rs/ || /^chr/)` in several ways and `print "chr"$0` is not equivalent to `$1="chr"$1; print`.

Comment: I assume for the second option you meant `!($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/)` ?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, writing codes in multiple lines may help you spot the mistake:

```
'{
    if (! ($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/)) {
        ($1 == "chr"$1); 
        print $0
    }
}; 
else {print $0}'
```

You will see that the `else` is out of the `{...}`

stay with your codes, this will fix the problem:

```
'{
    if (! ($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/)) {
        ($1 == "chr"$1); 
        print $0
    }else 
        print $0
}'
```

for the code improvement, check karakra's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way to write your code syntactically correctly is:

```
awk '!($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/) {$1="chr"$1} 1' filename > newfilename
```

but be warned that the assignment might change the white space in your file so what you probably really want is:

```
awk '!($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/) {sub(/^[[:space:]]*/,"&chr")} 1' filename > newfilename
```